# Xilinx fpga -: PYNQ-Z1

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am trying to connect to the PYNQ-Z1. I have followed each and every step precisely as mentioned in the docs but still when I try to access the browser by 192.168.2.99:9090, it tells me that the page is not working.

I have connected the board using a direct connection.
I use a mac so I wrote the image on the SD card using a dd command. The DONE light is on. The networking flashy blue light also come up with the four green lights which stay on. I am able to ssh into the board that means the networking is successful and for the time being I am able to do my work but it is still bothering me that why am I not being able to access the board using the browser.

Could anyone help me on this.

Comment: Could you assign an address from `192.168.2.` network to the network interface connected with your board?

Comment: I have assigned 192.168.2.98 to my local system and the fpga's address is the default one i.e. 192.168.2.99:9090.
And one more thing that i noticed was i am able to ssh to fpga but there I cannot ssh back into my computer. In fact, it is not even letting me ping my computer.

Answer (score -1):

There was a problem in the image. When I rewrote the image on the microsd, it started working directly without any issue.

Comment: Which version of image solves the problem according to you?